# ASP.NET MVC3 Model Error (Previous value in error message)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.  I have an integer field and as a test I am entering character values in the text box which are invalid for ints.

So when I test,

I enter an invalid value and click submit.

MVC passes back the following error message:

The value 'FF,' is not valid for FCode.

So then I erase the FF from the form field and enter HH, then click submit.  And then MVC gives me the following messages:

The value 'FF, HH' is not valid for FCode.

Then say I change the form field to BB, I get the following error returned:

The value 'HH, BB' is not valid for FCode.

It is always returning the latest 2 in the error message.  How can I fix this to only return the latest 1?  Users don't want to see their previous mistakes, they only want to see most recent.

Here is the code from my controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid){
//Do valid stuff here
}
else
{
     var query =
     from val in ModelState.Values
     where val.Errors.Count == 1
     select val.Errors;

     foreach (var error in query.ToList())
     {
          errorList.Add(error[0].ErrorMessage);
     }

     Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
     Response.StatusCode = 500;
     return Json(errorList);
}
```

Comment: Did you try the clear method before return?

Comment: I actually did and got same result.  I did ModelState.clear();

Comment: Where have your declared `errorList`? (as it is your code wont compile) If you inspect the value of `query` you should see only one item. I assume `errorList` must be a static property or your caching it somewhere and continuing to add errors to it. And what is the point of this? At least use `var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new {propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage}); return Json(errors );` so you can match up errors with controls in your view. But why not use unobtrusive validation?

Comment: I have figured out what is causing this, but I still don't have a solution to fix it.  In the view, we are binding to the FCode field twice, one with a hidden and again with a field for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually binding to same field in the model twice.  That is what was causing this.  I was using a TextBoxFor and a HiddenFor on the same field.

So when MVC sent the model errors back to my controller on form submit, it was sending 2.

I changed my TextBoxFor to a TextBox and this solved the problem since it is now only bound to the hidden.

Comment: Whats the point of including a hidden field that's invalid and then advising the user that its invalid - the user can even see the value let alone change it!

Comment: We have some fields on our screen that in some instances are read only and other instances, they are editable.  The original creator of our screens (not me) did not like the way the read only field looked to the user so he made the text boxes disabled instead (when he could have just styled the read onlys with CSS).  Values of disabled fields do not get passed back in model so he used hiddens to bind to model and used jquery to make sure they stay in sync.